# ¿Como poder usar la propiedad params en .Net en un json?

Tags: .net

Como puedo usar la propiedad params dentro de un Json

```
  var request = new RestRequest()
            .AddJsonBody(new
            {
                jsonrpc = "2.0",
                method = "property.set",
                id = 2,
                params = new
                {
                    property = "image.window.main.source",
                    value = "L1 SDI A",
                }
            });
```

Es que estoy tratando de crear un objeto para una solicitud pero al momento de asignar params me genera un error, pero necesito dicha propiedad para poder enviar la solicitud, hay alguna manera de usar esa propiedad sin generar conflictos?

Comment: Por favor agrega el error que te genera (como texto). Pulsa en [edit] para modificar tu pregunta. Te recomiendo también que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar palabras claves como `params` como nombres de propiedades.

Según la documentación de [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#making-requests) (que es lo que entiendo estas usando), la serialización/deserialización se realiza usando `System.Text.Json`, por lo que puedes crear una clase y usar [JsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-7.0) para cambiar el nombre de la propiedad en el JSON

Ejemplo:

```
public class Respuesta
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("params")]
    public Parametros parametros { get; set; }
}
public class Parametros
{
    public string property { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
```

Y luego haces:

```
  var request = new RestRequest()
            .AddJsonBody(new Respuesta()
            {
                jsonrpc = "2.0",
                method = "property.set",
                id = 2,
                parametros = new Parametros()
                {
                    property = "image.window.main.source",
                    value = "L1 SDI A",
                }
            });
```